# Persistent Compilation Errors in nav2_controller on ROS2 Iron with Ubuntu 22.04 Despite Workspace Sourcing

Tags: nav2, build-from-source, compilation, ros-iron

**Description**:

I am facing ongoing compilation errors when trying to build the **nav2_controller** package from the Navigation2 repository on ROS2 Iron running on Ubuntu 22.04. Despite correctly cloning the Navigation2 repository from the ROS2 Iron branch and including all related packages like nav2_msgs, the issue persists.

**Updated Steps to Reproduce**:

1. Set up a ROS2 Iron environment on Ubuntu 22.04.
2. Clone the Navigation2 repository from the ROS2 Iron branch.
3. Rebuild the workspace and source it.
4. Attempt to build the **nav2_controller** package using **colcon**.

**Expected Behavior:**
The **nav2_controller** package should compile without errors.

**Actual Behavior:**
The compilation of nav2_controller fails with multiple errors related to missing enum members in **nav2_msgs::action::FollowPath::Result**. Additionally, sourcing the workspace produces errors indicating that certain packages cannot be found.

**Error Output:**

**Sourcing the workspace:**

```
not found: "/home/rota_2024/nav2_gps_ws/install/nav2_recoveries/share/nav2_recoveries/local_setup.bash"
not found: "/home/rota_2024/nav2_gps_ws/install/nav2_controller/share/nav2_controller/local_setup.bash"
```

**Compilation errors in nav2_controller**:

```
[Include the error details from the terminal output here]
error: ‘INVALID_CONTROLLER’ is not a member of ‘nav2_msgs::action::FollowPath::Result’
... [other similar errors regarding members not found in nav2_msgs::action::FollowPath::Result] ...
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

Verified message definitions in **nav2_msgs**.
Rebuilt the workspace including all dependencies.
Ensured that there were no custom modifications affecting compatibility.
Cleaned and rebuilt specific packages facing issues.

**Additional Context:**

ROS2 Version: Iron
Ubuntu Version: 22.04
Navigation2 Branch: ROS2 Iron branch

**Request**:
I am seeking assistance in resolving these compilation errors and the issues encountered when sourcing the workspace. Any insights into why these specific members are missing, or suggestions for troubleshooting the sourcing errors, would be greatly appreciated.